# Is it possible to reverse a sha256 hashed value if we know part of the input value?

Tags: cryptography, hash, salt, sha256

I'm a total noob, so please help me out.
Suppose something is hashed in sha256. If we know the value of some part of the hashed text, can we figure out the entire text?

```
Ex: xxxxxx + j4l58jl6j4l6j4 = 64j1l5l64lkh41l654kj165l4j1566ghj6ghj6g1.
```

All are hypothetical values. So, we know that the value on the right hand side is the final hashed value, is it possible to figure out the value of xxxxxx?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to invent keyed hashing. Stop. Use HMAC. You might be interested in reading up on MAC in general. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code

Comment: To answer your specific question, not much faster than brute force. But, you are not interested in cryptography trivia, you are trying to build some kind of real system that has some kind of practical guarantees, and for that you must not use a construct you have invented. Use HMAC for symmetric signatures. Use a real password hash (pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypts, argon2) for password storage. Use other correct solutions for other problems.

Comment: Cryptographic Hash functions cannot have the reverse since they are one way functions. Many asked the inverting SHA256 since the Bitcoin uses SHA256d. What is the size of the unknown part? If less than around 91 bit, some [collective powers like Bitcoin Miners can search](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298). What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can we Calculate/Figure out/Find out? = **NO**

Can we efficiently *Bruteforce*? = YES

*--- ANSWER BELOW IS FOR BRUTEFORCE ---*

By the design of Cryptographic Hash Functions, they are *'one way'*. i.e. can not be *reversed*.

But *just in case* you stumble upon this scenario (**super rare in real-world and common in CTFs**).

You can use Hashcat(tool) to Bruteforce with masking to bruteforce just initial characters.

E.g.
Hash (sha256) = **c0489750c13b64906237515b5b944e0d9fe9380dfc2f60cc29ca2c88514c0a38**

Plain Text = ***XXXX*h_Example**

(X - Unknown)

Constraint = printable ASCII and Numbers

Hashcat mask = ?a?a?a?a

Hashcat mode = 1400 (SHA2-256)

command =

```
hashcat -m 1400 c0489750c13b64906237515b5b944e0d9fe9380dfc2f60cc29ca2c88514c0a38 -a 3 ?a?a?a?ah_Example
```

so this will reduce the time significantly while brute force. Try the above example
you might see something like :

```
x64mayhem$ hashcat -m 1400 C0489750C13B64906237515B5B944E0D9FE9380DFC2F60CC29CA2C88514C0A38 -a 3 ?a?a?a?ah_Example
hashcat (v5.1.0) starting...

...

OpenCL Platform #1: NVIDIA Corporation
======================================
* Device #1: GeForce MX150, 500/2002 MB allocatable, 3MCU

Hashes: 1 digests; 1 unique digests, 1 unique salts
Bitmaps: 16 bits, 65536 entries, 0x0000ffff mask, 262144 bytes, 5/13 rotates

Applicable optimizers:
* Zero-Byte
* Early-Skip
* Not-Salted
* Not-Iterated
* Single-Hash
* Single-Salt
* Brute-Force
* Raw-Hash

Minimum password length supported by kernel: 0
Maximum password length supported by kernel: 256
...
<snip>
...

Approaching final keyspace - workload adjusted.  

c0489750c13b64906237515b5b944e0d9fe9380dfc2f60cc29ca2c88514c0a38:hAa5h_Example
                                                 
Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Cracked
Hash.Type........: SHA2-256
Hash.Target......: c0489750c13b64906237515b5b944e0d9fe9380dfc2f60cc29c...4c0a38
Time.Started.....: Mon Aug  3 09:02:41 2020 (4 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Mon Aug  3 09:02:45 2020 (0 secs)
Guess.Mask.......: ?a?a?a?ah_Example [13]
Guess.Queue......: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.#1.........: 15592.6 kH/s (0.11ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:32 Thr:256 Vec:1
Recovered........: 1/1 (100.00%) Digests, 1/1 (100.00%) Salts
Progress.........: 48369440/81450625 (59.38%)
Rejected.........: 0/48369440 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 0/95 (0.00%)
Restore.Sub.#1...: Salt:0 Amplifier:509120-509152 Iteration:0-32
Candidates.#1....: hAaeh_Example -> RWj h_Example
Hardware.Mon.#1..: Temp: 51c Util: 61% Core:1721MHz Mem:3003MHz Bus:4

Started: Mon Aug  3 09:02:38 2020
Stopped: Mon Aug  3 09:02:45 2020
```

**on GPU*

Comment: [Related](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/110956).